# Question on Residues (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f(z)$ be given by
$$f(z)={a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}\over b_0+b_1z+\cdots+b_nz^n}$$ 
$b_n\neq 0$. Assume that zeroes of denominator are simple. Show that the sum of residues of f(z) at its poles is equal to $\frac{a_{n-1}}{b_n}$.

My Attempt : I tried approaching through residue by first assuming that the $n$ poles of $f(z)$ are $\{A_1,\ A_2,\ A_3,\ \cdots,\ A_n\}$ and I don't know what to do next. Maybe one way could be the theorem that sum of residues at poles is same as the residue at infinity. but how to use that in this question

Any help is greatly appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble reading your post because of the formatting. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Please make sure that my edits retained the meaning of your original question.

Comment: @EuYu Thank you so much sir !! Your edits are correct, i was trying to get this happen since last 15 mins with the help content provided. RThanks...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
 Sum of *all* residues of $f(z),$ including the residue at infinity, equals $0.$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i approached that way. That means that if i find the residue at infinity, the sum of residues will be negative of that value.

and for finding that that residue at infinity i will need to integrate it . how to go about that ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above hint,in your case $R(f,\infty)=-\lim_{|z|\to\infty} zf(z)$, Can you see now why $R(f,\infty)=-\frac {a_{n-1}} {b_n}$?

Comment: i understand the equation given by you but could not apply it to the question. i am stuck at some silly point i think...for solving the limit do we taze z out common from the denominator ?

Comment: take $z^n$ common from numerator and denominator